# How to select the memory cache and disk cache

Tags: google-chrome, caching

I have a question that makes me confused.I have tried to understand it,but I cannot solve the problem,so I have to commit a question.

When I open a website,I find some files hit the memory cache, some files hit the disk cache,and I compare these files,but I cannot get any result, I want to know how the browser choose the cache.